# How to implement declarative HTTP clients with many optional parameters in Micronaut?

Tags: rest, micronaut

I would like to use Micronaut's declarative HTTP client to interact with a REST API having many optional query parameters in its GET methods.

Example: There is an API to GET alarms where what alarms are returned is specified as query parameters. I could use the API with the following method:

```
@Client("/alarm/alarms")
public interface AlarmApi {
  @Get 
  Single<Alarms> getAlarms(Optional<String> source, Optional<OffsetDateTime> from, Option<OffsetDateTime> to, Optional<Status> status, Optional<Severity> severity, Optional<Integer> pageSize, Optional<Boolean> order);
```

and query it using

```
alarms = alarmApi.getAlarms(source, Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.of(2000), Optional.empty());
```

which is not easy to use. Better (IMHO) would be to have something like

```
alarm = alarmApi.getAlarms().source(source).pageSize(2000);
```

Is there a way to do something like this "out of the box" with Micronaut's declarative client?

Comment: You said "I would prefer to use a builder-style approach" and then said "outside of wrapping the declarative API with a builder".  You do or do not want to use a builder approach?

Comment: I do want to use a builder approach, sorry for misleading phrasing. I edited the question to be hopefully more clear.

Comment: In Kotlin you could use the default values and have clear calls by named parameters. In java you could build that yourself, but as your default is Optional.empty anyway why not use a request Object and have there an autogenerated builder that is used to call the method kind of wrapped?